# Will the name-value pair of an input element with type button be passed in the body of the post request upon form submission with the other data?

Tags: javascript, forms

`<input type="button" name="justabutton" value="I'm just a button">`

Will the value name pair of the button be sent in the the post request upon submitting the form?

I tried to use the input of button type as textinput by storing some data into its name attribute and pass it in the post body but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this form. Before pressing "Run code snippet" open the dev tools in your browser and open the network tab. Try clicking both  buttons and see what happens. The `type="button"` doesn't do anything. The `type="submit"` does a GET request that looks like this: `/post.php?justasubmitbutton=I%27m+just+a+submit+button`.

##### Conclusion

The value of the `type="button"` is not send in the submit event, but the value of `type="submit"` will.

```html
<form name="form01" action="post.php">
  <input type="button" name="justabutton" value="I'm just a button">
  <input type="submit" name="justasubmitbutton" value="I'm just a submit button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't be sent in the `POST` request. The only button that's automatically included in the post request is the submit button that you clicked on to submit the form (if the form is submitted due to pressing Return in the last text field, it's as if you clicked on the first submit button).

So the value of a button with `type="button"` will never be sent automatically.

Use a `type="hidden"` input to pass extra values to the server, not a button.